# How to give a counterexample of this estimate related to Paley-Littlewood theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, harmonic-analysis, littlewood-paley-theory

I am studying Paley-Littlewood theorem in Harmonic analysis, and I met an exercise. I would like to construct a function $f$ as a counterexample to show that the inequality
\begin{equation}
\| f \|^2_p \leq C \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} \| P_j f\|^2_p,
\end{equation}
is not true when $p<2,$ and here $C$ is a constant number only related to $f.$   Here,$P_j$ is the Paley-Littlewood operator. More explicitly, for $\beta(x) \in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbf{R}^n)$ and ${\rm supp}\,{
\beta} \subset \{1/2<|x|<2 \},$ and satisfying $1=\sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} \beta(2^{-j}x), x \neq 0.$ We define the Fourier transform of $P_j f$ is $\beta(2^{-j}\xi)\hat{f}(\xi).$

My attempt is, the function $f$ has the following form: $f(x)=e^{2 \pi imx }\phi(x),$ here $m$ is a constant number to be determined, and $\phi(x)$ is a Schwartz function. If $m$ is properly selected, then for some $P_j$, we have $P_j f=0.$ But I am stuck here.

Can anybody help me? Some suggestions or reference books are welcomed!